# Script out XMLA for all databases

Tags: sql-server-2012, backup, ssas, scripting

I have several SSAS databases.  I only want to script out the XMLA for them on a nightly basis.  This will be a second tier backup in addition to the regular backups we have.

How do I auto-generate XMLA scripts for all the databases?

Comment: How were they deployed in the first place? If they were deployed through an SSAS project, to me at least, that seems like a backup already. Assuming the project files are in source control, which is backed up regularly.

Comment: Yes, some of them are in Source Control, but I want a snapshot of the database as is on Prod (with the new partitions, for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using powershell.

```
$serverName = "servername\instanceName" 
$outputFolder = "D:\data\"

## load the AMO and XML assemblies into the current runspace 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices") > $null 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Xml") > $null 
$dateStamp = (get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")

## connect to the server 
$svr = new-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server 
$svr.Connect($serverName) 
foreach ($db in $svr.Databases) 
{ 
    write-Host "Scripting: " $db.Name 
    $xw = new-object System.Xml.XmlTextWriter("$($outputFolder)DBScript_$($db.Name)_$($dateStamp).xmla", [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8) 
    $xw.Formatting = [System.Xml.Formatting]::Indented 
    [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Scripter]::WriteCreate($xw,$svr,$db,$true,$true) 
    $xw.Close() 
} 
$svr.Disconnect()
```

References :

- [Automating the Scripting of an SSAS database](https://web.archive.org/web/20190916191220/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/darrengosbell/archive/2010/02/22/ssas-automating-the-scripting-of-an-ssas-database.aspx)
- [PowerShell to Script SQL Analysis Service Database(XMLA Script) and ReApply on a different Server](https://www.sqltechnet.com/2013/08/powershell-to-script-sql-analysis.html)
- [SQL Server Analysis Services Backup in Powershell](https://web.archive.org/web/20160307001002/http://zakird.com/code/2011/06/20/backing-up-analysis-services-in-powershell)